# Error parsing JSON output from curl with jq in MAKEFILE

Tags: curl, makefile, jq

I'm trying to parse a JSON response from Github's API inside a MAKE file but I'm unable to do it. I can easily make it work in pure bash but when I try to do it in bash from within a MAKE file I get an error.

The error I get is:

> ```
> Invalid string: control characters from U+0000 through U+001F must be escaped 
> at line 322, column 22
> ```

Here's the code in my MAKE file

```bash
get_assets:
    @json=$$(curl -s "https://api.github.com/repos/realm/realm-swift/releases/latest"); \
    echo "$${json}" | jq -r '.assets[] | .name, .browser_download_url' | while read -r name ; do \
        read -r url; \
        echo "$$name" "$$url"; \
    done; \
```

I tried a bunch of stuff like using printf instead of echo to pipe the output to jq, using `jq -Rr`, etc. to no avail.

**UPDATE**

If I save the cURL output to a file and then pipe the contents of that file using cat into jq all works as intended.

```bash
get_assets:
    @curl -s "https://api.github.com/repos/realm/realm-swift/releases/latest" > /tmp/realm.txt; \
    cat /tmp/realm.txt | jq -r '.assets[] | .name, .browser_download_url' | while read -r name ; do \
        read -r url; \
        echo "$$name" "$$url"; \
    done; \
```

The above code works correctly but I would rather pipe the cURL output directly into jq instead of having to first save it into a file...

Comment: Does `curl ... | jq -r '...' | while read ...` work?

Comment: Is this relevant? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/525496/parse-error-invalid-string-control-characters-from-u0000-through-u001f-must

Comment: @knittl unfortunately not... same error message...

Comment: @Jon I tried those solutions before posting my issue here. Unfortunately they don't work either :(

Comment: I created a `Makefile` and used your exact `make` rule (I added `.PHONY: get_assets`), and it echos 8 lines with no errors.  I wonder if this is a `curl` or maybe even a `locale` issue.  If you add `--header "Accept: application/json"` to the curl command, is there any difference?

Comment: I can't replicate the problem. The original code works in CentOS 7 and Cygwin(!), both with and without DOS line endings. I'm thinking there is a stray control character in your Makefile. If you inspect the file with `od -c` can you see any control characters?

Answer (score 1):

You say: *when I try to do it in bash from within a MAKE file I get an error.*

But, `make` does not invoke bash.  Make invokes `/bin/sh`.  One some systems, such as Red Hat and derived systems, `/bin/sh` is actually bash.  But on other systems, such as Debian and derived systems (including Ubuntu), `/bin/sh` is a simple POSIX shell (typically `dash`) which doesn't have all of bash's extra features.

You don't say what operating system you're testing on so I have no idea of this is actually your problem, but instead of writing your script at the command prompt for testing with make you should test it using `/bin/sh -c 'my command'` because that's how make will invoke it.

If you want to have your recipes run with bash instead of the POSIX standard `/bin/sh` you must set it in your makefile:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
```